# SQL group by output specific data

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ID     tag      index 
001       1     fsklgg
001       2     segwrh
001       3     esfjkg
002       4     seggrg
002       5     gehewv
002       6     egwgsg
003       1     esgges
003       4     yjkdsa
003       9     wrfsbb
```

I want to make output by the rule

```
1. each ID will only have one output
2. the output will be  sort by "tag" which is the largest
```

like this

```
ID     tag      index 
001       3     esfjkg
002       6     egwgsg
003       9     wrfsbb
```

but my answer is always

```
ID     tag      index 
001       1     fsklgg
002       4     seggrg
003       1     esgges
```

I use GROUP BY tag, but the answer will be the smallest one.
I tried to use ORDER BY DESC ,hope that the answer would change, but it does not work.
Can anyone teach me how to approach the answer?
Or what command should  I use?

My source code is

```
SELECT
t1.`藥品代碼` AS ID,
t1.`藥價參考截止日期` AS tag,
t1.`藥價參考金額` AS `index`,
t1.`藥品英文名稱` AS index2,
t1.`藥價參考日期` AS index3,
t1.ATC_CODE AS index4
FROM
    `健保用藥品項查詢檔` AS t1
GROUP BY
ID
HAVING
id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
id ASC,
tag ASC
```

using MariaDB

Comment: Please tag the database that you are using and post sample and desired output data.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t1.ID,
       t1.tag,
       t1.index
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, MAX(tag) AS tag
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY ID
) t2
    ON t1.ID  = t2.ID AND
       t1.tag = t2.tag
ORDER BY t1.tag
```

Using a subquery:

```
SELECT t1.ID,
       t1.tag,
       t1.index
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE t1.tag = (SELECT MAX(tag) FROM yourTable WHERE ID = t1.ID)
```

Comment: I've never heard of a DB not having `INNER JOIN` available, and joining should be faster than using a subquery.  What tool are you using?

Comment: err. my mistake, I suppose that means my code is wrong...
I changed a few times and got

[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'ID' in 'field list'

Comment: Thank you.
Subquery works
But all tag become the same as the biggest one of all, not the biggest one each，how should I fix that?

Comment: There is something strange with your setup.  You can't join, and the subquery is off.  I think you either have miscopied the query, or your data has a problem.

Comment: My database is actually chinese(all rows), so I use AS 'a' or other simple words to make it easy to look, but I think that's what make it unjoinable.
I rename all of them back(with super long chinese words), and the first example of inner join works. Its running now, I'll give more feed back after it finished, thank you.

Comment: Hmmm...there may an encoding problem then, or you are just using aliases incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as well:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM tableA a
WHERE EXISTS(
     SELECT ID, tag FROM (
              SELECT ID, MAX(tag) tag FROM tableA GROUP BY ID) t 
WHERE t.id = a.id AND t.tag = a.tag) 
ORDER BY a.tag DESC
```

Comment: It can be simplified like this `SELECT a.*
 FROM   tableA a
 WHERE  tag = (SELECT Max(tag)
      FROM   tableA T
      WHERE  t.id = a.id)`

Comment: The program just kept running...I dont know whats wrong, but thank you anyways